# Trying to remove the redundant code but unable to solve the issue, any assistance would be helpful

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Following code creates a functional component with multiple arrays of object that I want to display in the UI, I am repeating a lot of code and I want to make it clean and remove any redundant code. The code works properly but the only issue is with refactoring the code and removing the redundant part.

```
function About() {
    const title = "we are a team";
    // leadership array.
    const leadership = [
        {
            name: "abc",
            department: "abc",
            phone: "abc",
            email: "abc",
        },
        {
            name: "abc",
            department: "abc",
            phone: "abc",
            email: "abc",
        },
    ];
    
    // business array
    const business = [
        {
            name: "abc",
            department: "abc",
            email: "abc",
        },
        {
            name: "abc",
            department: "abc",
            email: "abc",
        },
    ];
    
    // mapping through the leadership array and displaying the content in the UI
    const row1 = leadership.map((row) => (
        <div className="column">
            <div className="card">
                <div className="container">
                    <h2>{row.name}</h2>
                    <p>{row.department}</p>
                    <p>{row.phone}</p>
                    <p>{row.email}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    ));
    
    // mapping through the leadership array and displaying the content in the UI
    const row2 = business.map((row) => (
        <div className="column">
            <div className="card">
                <div className="container">
                    <h2>{row.name}</h2>
                    <p>{row.department}</p>
                    <p>{row.email}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    ));
    
    // returning the content and rendering it in the UI
    return (
        <div className="home-component">
            <div className="home-content">
                <h1 style={stylesheader}> Meet the team </h1>
                <h2 style={stylehead}>{title}</h2>

                <h2 style={styles}> Leadership </h2>
                <div className="row" style={style1}>
                    {row1}
                </div>

                <h2 style={styles}> Business Development </h2>
                <div className="row" style={style1}>
                    {row2}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default About;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to avoid repetition wherever possible, so in your code I would move each of the `<h2>` blocks into a simple function, such as:

```
h2Renderer(title, rowData) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2 style={styles}>{ title }</h2>
            <div className="row" style={style1}>
              {
                rowData.map((row, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={ `h2row-${index}` } className="column">
                           <div className="card"> 
                              <div className="container">
                                  <h2>{row.name}</h2>
                                  <p>{row.department}</p>
                                  { row.phone ? <p>{row.phone}</p> : null }
                                  <p>{row.email}</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    );
                });
              }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Since 'phone' seems to be optional, the ["ternary expression"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) `'{ row.phone ? <p>{row.phone}</p> : null }'` will add 'phone' if it is a property of the row object.

Call this h2Renderer() in your render function 'return' statement, for each set of rows, and also pass in the title:

```
return (
     <div className="home-component">
        <div className="home-header">
        <Header/>
        </div>
        <div className="home-content" >
            <h1 style={stylesheader}> Meet the team </h1>
            <h2 style={stylehead}>{title}</h2>
            { this.h2Renderer(" Leadership ", row1 ) }
            { this.h2Renderer(" Business Development ", row2 ) }
            { this.h2Renderer(" Algorithm Development ", row3 ) }
            { this.h2Renderer(" Software Development ", row4 ) }
        </div>
        <Footer/>
     </div>
    );
}
```

Later on, I'm sure you can reduce the lines of code by passing in the arrays of data, and the 'title' headers as props to your component, and use the props in the h2Renderer instead of passing arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Later on, I'm sure you can reduce the lines of code by passing in the arrays of data, and the 'title' headers as props to your component, and use the props in the h2Renderer instead of passing arguments.  {Can you please tell me how to do this?  I am new and learning concepts it would be of great help if you could tell me how to do this.Thanks}

Comment: 'props' are how you pass data into your react components from parent components. In your code, you have hardcoded the arrays of data to be rendered by your component, however in future you'll want to make it more dynamic, perhaps passing the results of some HTTP requests, or DB queries into your components as props, and render your components with that data. You should have a good look at the react tutorials and documentation here (https://facebook.github.io/react/), it might help to clarify things, and perhaps raise a lot more questions. Best of luck!

Comment: function H2Renderer (props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2 style={styles}>{ props.team }</h2>
            <div className="row" style={style1}>
              {
               props.role.map((row, index) => {
       return (
<div key={ `h2row-${index}` } className="column">
<div className="card"> 
<div className="container">
<h2>{row.name}</h2>
<p>{row.department}</p>
{ row.phone ? <p>{row.phone}</p> : null }
<p>{row.email}</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
                    );
                })
              }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

Comment: <H2Renderer team=" Leadership " role={leadership} />
                    <H2Renderer team=" Business Development " role={business}/>
                    <H2Renderer team=" Algorithm Development " role={algorithm}/>
                    <H2Renderer team=" Software Development " role={developer}/>